# How to configure BlueStacks App Player to use Proxy settings when connecting to Network?

Tags: proxy, bluestacks

[Bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com/) allows running of Android apps on Windows by emulating the Android OS image.

I recently installed BlueStacks_HD_AppPlayerPro (0.7.0.725) on Windows XP but was not able to download/install any apps because my network requires a proxy. It shows the following error:

[image]

I tried using ProxyCaps like freecap, but it did not work for me. How can I configure BlueStacks to use my proxy settings?

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but recently I have installed AMD AppZone (based on BlueStacks) and it works smoothly on my laptop behind a proxy, without no particular settings. Have you tested it? Maybe in a recent version they have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

*The other answers are way out of date.*

**BlueStacks installations now includes a command-line utility** `HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe` to setup a proxy connection. I can't find documentation for this utility anywhere but it's pretty basic:

---

## Using BlueStacks with a Proxy Server

1. Open **BlueStacks**. (It has to be open before running the utiity)
2. Open a Windows **command prompt**.

   - (eg. hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  →
     type `cmd` → hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> )
3. Change to the **BlueStacks program folder**.

   - (eg. `cd C:\Program Files\BlueStacks` )
4. **Run `HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe`** :

> **Usage**:
>
> ```
>      HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe set <host> <port>      connect to specified proxy
>      HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe reset                  reset/stop using proxy
> ```
>
> For example: `HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe set 123.45.67.890 4444`

5. When prompted, **close and re-open** BlueStacks.

Alternatively, you can specify other proxy protocols by including it in the `<host>` in standard syntax.  For example, I used `socks://localhost` and my custom port number. It took a couple tries but it worked eventually.

---

### To disconnect / reset BlueStacks proxy settings  :

1. Make sure BlueStacks is **running**
2. Open a **command prompt**
3. Run command: **`C:\Program Files\BlueStacks\HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe reset`**
4. **Close and re-open** BlueStacks.

Comment: but using this method, requests from apps (apk) don't go through the proxy. only from the actual BlueStacks.exe does (like when you click the notification icon)

Comment: Setting the proxy worked for me.  Resetting the proxy did not.  I gotta reinstall it now, and it didn't cache the install files.

Comment: what version of bluestacks did you try this on? bluestacks 10 and 5 don't seem to have `HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe`

Comment: Not working for `C:\Program Files\BlueStacks\HD-ConfigHttpProxy.exe set 127.0.0.1 8888` while I use Charles as proxy

Answer (score 5):

According to Bluestack employee Deepika Sharma:

> Currently, we do not support proxy settings in BlueStacks App Player but will definitely consider it in our future release.

This information came from their help forum thread: [No network access behind a proxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140421161908/https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/no_network_access_behind_a_proxy).

---

Alex Guerrieri answered stating that it was able to work around this issue using the application you've mentioned. I'm posting a solution here, as I don't know what you have tried:

> I found a solution. I used proxycap to redirect Bluestacks through proxy (even with LDAP). You have to download and install the application, set your proxy and create a new rule for HD-Network.exe (found under Bluestack directory in %Program_Files%). It worked for me.

Comment: did you try Alex's solution? I tried using a program similar to proxycap, called [freecap](http://www.freecap.ru). But I still got a "Network Unreachable" error.

Comment: @akjain I didn't tried yet! My answer was the "not supported" part. I end up mentioning Alex steps to workaround this issue, since you haven't specified which steps you took to try a workaround. I'll give it a go and see if I can came up with a functional workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have being able to use BlueStacks on my network using cntlm + Proxifier. I use cntlm to authenticate on my proxy and Proxifier as a replacement for Proxycaps/WideCap. Proxifier lets you tunnel your socks connections through the cntlm proxy (http://proxifier.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPN android app that supports proxy (e.g. AgoVPN) then connect to the VPN and you will access the internet in BlueStacks. I tested it in Bluestack 5 in Windows 10.