# BlueStacks with proxy

Tags: proxy, bluestacks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure BlueStack AppPlayer to use Proxy settings when connecting to Network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27224/how-to-configure-bluestack-appplayer-to-use-proxy-settings-when-connecting-to-ne)

I am using BlueStacks 0.7.7.813. I want to run apps like whatsapp on my laptop and the internet is connected with proxy. Is there any way to run apps like whatsapp on BluStacks behind proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of: [How to configure BlueStack AppPlayer to use Proxy settings when connecting to Network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27224/how-to-configure-bluestack-appplayer-to-use-proxy-settings-when-connecting-to-ne)

The answer is `NO`; proxy is not yet supported.